# Fail2Ban blocking everything on every port, no access

Tags: ssh, iptables, fail2ban

I copied the jail.conf to jail.local and used the Default jail to block IPs on every port with the default bantime etc. I also changed "enabled" to true.
After restarting the service, I was kicked out of the server and couldnt even access the website anymore, all services are unreachable. Tried switching IPs, called friends to try and access the website, nothing works.

It throws an kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset error when I try to ssh into the machine.

WHat can I do to regain access to my machine? (It's not physically accessible to me)

Comment: From your description it sounds like there is no other way to access the host except logging in locally via console. Is this a VM? And if yes, did you create a snapshot before doing the changes?

Comment: Yes it is a vm and no i did not create a snapshot. How f***** am I?

Comment: The default bantime of fail2ban is 10 minutes. But tbh, `connection reset` doesn't sound like it's been blocked by the firewall.

Comment: Well it's been 10 minutes and I still can't access anything. It just tells me Connection Reset.

Comment: [this](https://www.nixcraft.com/t/kex-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer-error-on-linux/3927) page suggests that the issue is firewall so it seems highly possible to be related to a misconfiguration of fail2ban

Comment: Is there any way I can get out of this mess? There very important docs on that machine...

Comment: In my opinion there is no way to get in without local console access. Try to restart the VM in case some config is not persisted and will not come into effect after the restart. But from your description this seems unlikely.

Comment: Is there a way to access the virtual machine over the physical console port of the host server?

Comment: In the future, arrange that firewall changes have a rollback command after say 30 seconds or so. That is, any changes will revert automatically after a time delay, so if all goes well you are only locked out for 30 seconds or whatever.

Comment: So you have access to the physical host in which the VM runs? What type of virtualization does it use? How did you (or whoever) create the VM?

Comment: The vm is at a facility with the host I chose. It's not accessible to me. I also don't have any details on what virtualization is used.

Comment: OK then you should contact your host and ask if there is any way to connect locally to the VM console

Comment: Yeah that's what I've been trying to do but they have this boundary between me and their techs called tech support, that won't let me talk to someone who could actually help me :/   But thank you so much for answering my questions!